# How can i convert the dictionary items into flat strings in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the dictionary of items from which i am generating the URLs like this

`request.build_absolute_uri("/myurl/" + urlencode(myparams))`

The output i am getting is like this

`number=['543543']&region=['5,36,37']`

but i want the url to be

`number=543543&region=5,36,37`

all those items are in `myparams dictionary`

Comment: Please print your `myparams`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably find for ease of use that passing `doseq=True` will be useful (albeit not exactly what you want - but does mean that any url parsing library should be able to handle the input without custom coding...)

```
>>> from urllib import urlencode
>>> a = range(3)
>>> urlencode({'test': a})
'test=%5B0%2C+1%2C+2%5D'
>>> urlencode({'test': a}, True)
'test=0&test=1&test=2'
```

Otherwise, you'll have to write custom code to `','.join(str(el) for el in your_list)` for values in `myparams` where it's a list/similar... (then `.split(',')` the other end)

Comment: you r the man buddy , u solved my problem , that was the next question i was going to ask

Comment: is there any way to get rid of empty items form the dictionary

Comment: @user194932147 do you mean entries such as `{'empty_list': [], 'empty_str': ''}` ?

Comment: yes , becaus ethere may be items which user don't fill in search page' like this `{u'project': [u'']`

Comment: @user194932147 Simplest is to just recreate the `dict` without empty values - newparams = `{k: v for k,v in myparams.iteritems() if v}`

Comment: I tried that but its tsill shows the item because it constains bloddy `u` like this `u''`

Comment: @user194932147 err no - the `u` isn't part of the string - it's just indicating the string is `unicode` instead of of type `str`... Are you sure it doesn't contain a space or something?

Comment: well i am not sure about space. how can we remove those if there any space or tab , i don't want to include those items in dict which are empty or have space or tabs

Comment: @user194932147 change the above to be `if v.strip()`

Answer (score 0):

looks like `myparams` is a `dict` that has `list`s as values.

```
new_params = dict(k, v[0] for k, v in dict.iteritems())
```

will construct a new dict.